# Limit the use of HTML tags in data entry for blog. MVC3 Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have created a textbox which I will be populating with stories. I need to limit the use of HTML tags which will be used to the following:

- P
- em
- strong
- a
- ol
- ul
- li

Is there a way of enforcing this.

Thanks’ in advance for any help or advice.

Comment: You want to limit it in the web browser or after it is posted back or both?

Comment: I would want to stop it from posting at the web browser - but also stop it from updating the database with the tags

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this [html sanitizer](http://refactormycode.com/codes/333-sanitize-html). I believe it is what stack overflow uses.
It uses a whitelist approach where you can define the set of 'safe' html tags.